# Why magento does not provide Guide or Manual for developers?

Tags: documentation, magento

Does anyone know why magento does not provide any manual or developer guide? 
All most every framework and CMS provides an official development manual but in the case of magento I did not find any official manual which surprised me.

Learning magento is hard because they are making this thing hard.

Comment: I suggest that you rephrase your question to make it less argumentative.  E.g. "Where can I find the best guide to Magento as a Developer".  You are much more likely to get a helpful response that way

Comment: It seems the documentation is now available at [docs.magentocommerce.com](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/). ew, they are using framesets..

Comment: And also for examples, go through sites like Smashing magazine and Sitepoint. and of course, magento's official blog (knowledge base).

Comment: https://github.com/aleron75/mageres it may helpful to start learn magento. Magento official site didn't provide more dedicated guide and documentation for developer :(

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The best resource you will find is Alan Storm's [blog](http://alanstorm.com/) and he has recently written an oustanding series on the Knowledge Base called "[Magento for Developers](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-1-introduction-to-magento)".  Both of those will give you exactly what you are asking for in terms of customizing Magento.  First, you must know the framework, then you can understand how to customize and extend it.  Otherwise you are just hacking.